# R cropping the right hand border of a chart

Tags: r

I created a chart using chart_Series but I want to remove the RHS y axis labels by cropping within R, rather than using an external program

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to=Sys.Date())


myTheme <- chart_theme()
myTheme$rylab <- FALSE

chart1 <- chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme)

add_TA(SMA(SPY[,4],20),on=1)
```

But how can I crop the chart to remove the right hand border and also the labels on the rhs y axis?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an external application that is designed to carve up images. R will try to fit the image into the available space and throw an error if it won't fit. Perhaps you only mean to remove the whitespace. If so, follow nico and use `par(mar=c(5,4,4,0)+.1)`

Comment: I am using an external application at the moment, however I need to do this a large number of times so a solution within R would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set margins using `par`.

```
par(mar=c(bottom, left, top, right))
```

The default is

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+.1)
```

Margins are expressed in lines.
See `?par` for more information.

---

**EDIT**: it seems I misunderstood the question, but the answer still lies in `par`!

```
par(bty='c')
```

Will plot a "C" box (i.e. only top, left and bottom).
Other possible values of `bty` include:

`n` : no box (you can add a customized box using the `box` function)
`7` : only top and right
`l` : only bottom and left
`]` : no left border
`u` : no top border

If needed you can also pass `bty` directly to plot such as:

```
plot(x, y, bty="n")
```

Comment: Maybe that is what is needed. I read the request differently. I thought it was requested to remove the right side of the bounding box.

Comment: @DWin: ahhhh... possibly you're right. Well, I'll leave the answer until we get more info on what actually is needed...

Comment: That is correct, I am trying to remove the right side of the box

Comment: I am also trying to remove labels on a rhs y axis

Comment: @adam.888: please then post a reproducible example of what you are trying to do... how are you making the right axis? There are various way to achieve that, but not knowing what exactly you are doing does not help.

Comment: I apologize, I tried to use a simple example so as to  not over complicate the question. I have changed it as you correctly suggested.

Comment: @adam.888: no worries. As for your problem, it looks like you need to fiddle around with the code of the `add_ta` function (try `fix(add_ta)`) to remove the right axis...